# Basic cookiecutter-flask implementation

Tags: python-2.7, flask, cookiecutter

So I have got my app up and running. However it still runs off the *cmd* console at the moment. Next steps is for me to build a simple web app interface.

After much research, rather than to setup an entire flask site from scratch. I decided to use cookiecutter-flask from https://github.com/konstantint/cookiecutter-flask boilerplate to quickly get the boilerplate up and running.

Everything looks good in a sense where I understand:

1. Templating
2. App function
3. Static

I still cannot figure out how to get the user registration function working. I keep getting a wsgi error. I know is somewhat related to my database not being installed.

Not specific to that, what I am really looking for is a walk through tutorial on how to get it working by bare minimum and then enhance from there.

I have been looking around for tutorials and walk through but to no avail.

Appreciate any help out there.

Comment: Don't you have the any button saying ' Create Account '  ?

Comment: I do, but I when i try to, I am returned an error 'sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError'

Comment: Did you init the db ?

Comment: Unsure how to do that. Would love to have a step by step on how to get it up and going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clone you have to do these steps ... These will create the database tables for you...

1. python manage.py db init
2. python manage.py db migrate
3. python manage.py db upgrade
4. python manage.py server

Comment: Wow just like that. Is there a tutorial or any reference that you can share for me to learn more?